# Unity Copying GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, copy-paste, scene, gameobject

I am trying to copy a gameObject from one scene to another, but once I copy it, it gets deformed, I am not sure why this is happening, I thought about the resolution but both scenes have the same resolution/size.

Here is the 1st scene:

[image]

Here is the 2nd scene where I want to copy it:
[image]

I am not copying the buttons only the top white square.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for general unity quesions, use a unity forum for this quesion!

Comment: I didnt know that thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pack all object you want to a parent object, then copy this parent object.